# boto3 get_log_events does not return10,000 data

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am tryin to get log events information from AWS Cloudwatch using boto3. In this documentation   https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_log_events

its written that cloudwatch api will return max **10000** records . But I am only getting  **977** records. I tried to change the **startime** and **endtime** but the result is the same. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
response = client.get_log_events(logGroupName=logGroupName,
                                     logStreamName=logStreamName, 
                                     startTime=yesterday, # yestarday
                                     endTime=today, #today
                                     limit = 10000,
                                     startFromHead=True)
```

Comment: `The maximum number of log events returned. If you don't specify a value, the maximum is as many log events as can fit in a response size of 1 MB, up to 10,000 log events.` I'm guessing the limit of 1MB is what is causing the response to be restricted to 977 records. You'll have to use a paginator class, or write the necessary code to handle checking and using the `nextToken` entry in the response, to call `get_log_events()` multiple times.